# OOP Method Usage

Tags: c#, oop, methods

I would like to ask if I have a class Person and Food,
and I want to have method of "eat".

Should I put eat method in class Person or method eaten in class Food ?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends that you say Person.Eat(food) or Food.EatenBy(person)

Comment: So either way is correct ?
Thank you

Comment: An active verb, e.g. "eat", generally makes more sense as a method. A corresponding "eaten" property would also make sense. Not hard and fast rules, but a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends that you say Person.Eat(food) or Food.EatenBy(person)

If you preffer `Person.Eat(food)`

```
public class Person
{
    public void Eat(Food food)
    { 
        //...
    }
}
```

If you preffer  `Food.EatenBy(person)`

```
public class Food
{
    public void EatenBy(Person person)
    { 
        //...
    }
}
```